# How to add the typed value in textfield as in update

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a firebase CRUD flutter app. I want to show the typed value in textfield as in update. So that users can update the value by erasing the typed value.

Answer (score 0):

//define

```
var _fNameController = TextEditingController();
```

//set value which one you set

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _fNameController.text = 'jayesh';
    super.initState();
  }
```

// textfield

```
      TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            controller: _fNameController,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
            
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'First Name',
              //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            validator: validator.validatefName,
          ),
```

Comment: using controller you can set value in textfield